# おる in honorific contexts

Tags: words, honorifics, keigo

Usually, we're told that おる is a humble verb, and that mostly holds true. But sometimes I see it conjugated to a light honorific form おられる, usually when talking about someone to whom respect must be shown rather than to them. I'd like to ask how this comes about.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, it's not a Standard Japanese. But おる is a normal verb in many dialects in western Japan, and the speakers in those regions won't consider おられる really unnatural. Recently, it has infiltrated into the east as well.