# what does てはいる in this sentence mean?

Tags: nuances

> 彼は、興奮して、もったいぶった顔つきをし**てはいる**が、内心の喜びを、上品ぶった冷静さの態度でかくそうとしていた。

also in the following sentence is the same てはいる used but with the humble equivalent おる if so why is it used in its passive form?

> あいつの話など、一言も信じてはおられないでしょうな？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 彼は、興奮して、もったいぶった顔つきをして**は**いるが、内心の喜びを、上品ぶった冷静さの態度でかくそうとしていた。

This は is a plain contrast marker. He is もったいぶった顔つきをしている externally, but 興奮している internally. One can also say "もったいぶった顔つき**は**しているが" in this context.

> あいつの話など、一言も信じて**は**おられないでしょうな？

- おる here is not humble, but a neutral and a bit dialectal equivalent of いる. And this れる is to form an honorific expression, not passive. So おられる is basically the same as いらっしゃる. See: [おる in honorific contexts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010)
- は appears far more often in negative sentences. See: [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010) In this sentence, this は is not really strongly contrastive, but is used to add an emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

している == Te-form for expressing current status --  [ is being ... ]

In the 1st sentence (してはいる),  は is inserted to increase  contrast with what follows.

> 彼は、興奮して、もったいぶった顔つきをしてはいるが、内心の喜びを、上品ぶった冷静さの態度でかくそうとしていた。

[ He is appearing straight-faced BUT actually all excited inside. ]

Also grammatical without the は

---

> あいつの話など、一言も信じてはおられないでしょうな？

[ You don't believe a word of his, do you? ]

This is not passive.  Polite form. ( られ is used for both. )

> あいつの話など、一言も信じておられないでしょうな？

Grammatical without the は , but with it, there's more emphasis.