# What is おりません? Possible typo?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I was reading a joke:

> [長寿村]{ちょうじゅむら}
>
> [旅人]{たびびと}：この[村]{むら}は[世界一]{せかいいち}の[長生]{ながい}きの村だって？
>
> [村人]{むらびと}：はい、[未]{いま}だに[死]{し}んだ[人]{ひと}がおりません。
>
> 旅人：じゃ、あの[葬儀]{そうぎ}の[列]{れつ}はなんだ？
>
> 村人：はい、[葬儀屋]{そうぎや}が[自殺]{じさつ}をしたんです。

I understand most of the joke except the end of the second line:

> 死んだ人がおりません。

I see that おりません is used here and I don't understand why it is here. I checked the dictionary on my Mac for the word おる and it told me to look for おりる where I found 下りる, 降りる. After I read the meanings, I can't find anything that would make sense in this context.

Then I started to think that this is a typo and it should have been いません instead:

> 死んだ人がいません。

literally, "there does not exist a person who died".

Question: Is this a typo? If not, what is the meaning of おりません and how will the meaning change if I used いません?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In meaning,

> 「おる」＝「いる」 and
>
> 「おりません」＝「いません」

So, there is no typo here as 「おる」 is a dictionary word.  Think of it as a somewhat old-fashioned version of 「いる」.

The line in question is uttered by a villager, so one could say that 「おりません」 is being used as role language at least loosely.

「未だに死んだ人がおりません。」 means:

"***No one has ever died (here).***" or

"***There is no one who has died (here).***"

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that おる is still used in modern-day language in extremely formal situations.

Answer (score 2):

It's 居{お}る as in [http://jisho.org/word/居る-1](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%B1%85%E3%82%8B-1) .

> 死んだ人がおりません。

would be translated to

> There is no dead person.

Comment: Will it change the meaning of the sentence if I used いません here?

Comment: @Sweeper I think not. いる is also written 居る and have very similar meaning ( if any different )

Comment: "There s no dead person." would not be such an accurate translation.