# How would I translate ’期待されとっても倒れたら’ in this sentence

Tags: translation, passive-voice, dialects, contractions, kansai-ben

Here's the full sentence:

’なんぼ**期待されとっても倒れたら**元も子もないんやから。’

And here's where I ended up:

'Because no matter what you say, **even if you have hopes**, you'll lose everything **if you burn out**.'

The context is, this is something the main character's mother (who lives in Kochi prefecture in the Shikoku region), is saying. I decided that とって could be a contraction of とる (to have) but then I realized that means more like 'to have lunch' or 'to have a nap'. So does this make my translation wrong?

Here's another theory. So I found out that 〜んやから at the end of the sentence is colloquial Kansai-ben which could be characteristic of the Shikoku region with it's proximity to Kansai. So I decided to research colloquial contractions. I found that the contraction 〜てあいて changes to といて in Kansai-ben. I thought I saw somewhere on google that といて sometimes is とって. So if that's the case, could the translation be:

'Because whatever the circumstances, **if you're expecting to burn out**, you'll lose everything.'

Last theory is that it's とっても. I've just never seen とっても inserted mid-contraction like this. If this is grammatical, I suppose the translation could be:

'Because whatever the circumstances, **if you're expecting to really burn out**, you'll lose everything.'

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Kochi is in Shikoku, not Kansai. Whether that's irrelevant and the character speaks Kansai-ben anyway, or if there are just enough similarities with surrounding dialects, I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks for that correction! I was able to find that the Shikoku region uses Tosa-ben, which is largely a combination of the Kansai and Chugoku dialects according to the article below. Which means my Kansai-ben theories might still work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosa_dialect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 期待されとる is short of 期待されておる (see [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010)), and in this context [おる is the same as いる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010) for progressive aspect. なんぼ is the equivalent of いくら in Kansai/Shikoku dialect. や is widely used instead of だ in western Japan.

なんぼ期待されとっても、倒れたら元も子もないんやから。
= いくら期待されていても、倒れたら元も子もないんだから。
= No matter how much you are expected (No matter how much they expect on you), if you fall down, you'll lose everything.

Comment: Cool, I was closer than I thought. I really appreciate it!